# Why does the Einstein summation convention work out?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, index-notation

It seems as though in writing down all formulae of Riemannian geometry in local coördinates, the Einstein summation convention works mysteriously, and I don't have a clue as to the reason for that. Indeed, if we write all vectors in local coordinates, e.g.

$$
X = \lambda^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
$$

and run computations, it never once occurs that something cannot be written in the Einstein convention. But what is the reason for that?

Comment: You really need to write $dx^i$ instead of $dx_i$ for this to work. For a covariant tensor field, e.g., a differential form, you need $\mu_i\,dx^i$. Does this now give you a hint to answer your own question? :)

Comment: I guess what one would do is to induct over the possible formulae in Riemannian geometry, right? Some kind of structural induction over complexity.

Comment: What would it mean that an expression "cannot be written in the summation convention"?

Comment: For example, the location of the indices of the Christoffel symbols are fixed, and you can't write $\sum_{k=1}^n \Gamma_{ij}^k dx^k$ using Einstein convention, because we have an upper index.

Comment: You can write it, but it won't make a well-defined quantity (independent of coordinate chart).

Comment: @TedShifrin What would be the correct way to write it in Einstein convention?

Comment: The Christoffel symbols are a bad example, actually, as they are *not* components of a tensor field (look at their transformation rule when you change coordinates). But I was saying that if you *do* have a tensor, say, with components $a^i_j$, then you can *write* $\sum a^i_j dx^i\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$, but it won't make for something invariantly-defined. However, $\sum a^i_j dx^j\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ *is* invariantly-defined and gives a tensor field of type $(1,1)$.

Comment: Do you know about contraction of tensors? If you  do, you can solve your own puzzle.